# My Server Side Blazor app's Counter isn't incrementing when deployed to Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, blazor, blazor-server-side

I newed up a server side Blazor project ([formerly Razor Components](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/8931)) via `dotnet new razorcomponents -o MySampleApp`. It works as expected on my machine, when when I right click and attempt to publish to Azure, it fails with a

> HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

I solved this by using the "Self-Contained" Deployment Mode, which gets me to the expected Blazor example home page. The weather forecast page works, but the counter page fails to increment. How can I fix this?

Comment: No man, formerly [server-side Blazor](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/8931) ;)

Comment: Not anymore.  They changed it back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I needed to turn on websockets. Duh.

I found it under portal.azure.com > MySampleApp app service > Configuration > General Settings > Web sockets.

Also, apparently I can install the ASP.NET Core 3.0 Runtime in Extensions, which means I can go back to "Framework-Dependent" as a Deployment Mode. This video was a great help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GfazTDXH6JA